# ¿Cómo se hacen filtros para agregarlos en una aplicación android?

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un proyecto escolar y quiero hacer una aplicación similar a Instagram pero más sencilla en la que pueda agregar una foto de mi galería o tomarla de mi cámara y una vez teniéndola quiero poder ponerle filtros y guardarla ya resolví la parte de obtener la foto pero no sé cómo se hacen los filtros o como integrarlos en la aplicación

Comment: En que sentido hablas de filtros , filtrar las imagenes?

Comment: holoa no perdon la tardanza es en el sentido de poder aplicar filtros a las fotos tal y como se haria en instagram o retrica o b12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para aplicar filtros debes cambiar los parámetros de color de cada pixel que se conforma la imagen.

Prueba con ese código [extraído de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699810/how-to-change-bitmap-image-color-in-android)

```
Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
    float[] colorTransform = {
            0, 1f, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0f, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0f, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 1f, 0};

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(0f); //Remove Colour 
    colorMatrix.set(colorTransform); //Apply the Red

    ColorMatrixColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);   

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 

    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, (int)(display.getHeight() * 0.15), display.getWidth(), (int)(display.getHeight() * 0.75));            

    image.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

Y aquí  una [lista de filtros](http://alistapart.com/article/finessing-fecolormatrix) a aplicar usando la matriz de color

Una [librería con algunos efectos pre-diseñados](http://grishma102.blogspot.com.es/2013/10/apply-effects-on-image-using-effects.html)

**Update 2**

[Librería AndroidPhotoFilters](https://github.com/Zomato/AndroidPhotoFilters) para implementar algunos filtros básicos

[Libreria photofilter](https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/photofilter)
https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/photofilter

Comment: muchisimas gracias me ha servido mucho tu respuesta